# Steps to create standalone database of size 10gb on one of the nodes of rac cluster

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c, oracle-rac

I need to create a standalone database of size 15gb on one of the nodes on 3 node rac cluster.This is required for POC(testing -for implementing shareplex).Please provide the exact steps to create this database.

Comment: Just use the DBCA utility to create it.  The fact that there is already a database, and that existing database is part of a cluster, is irrelevent.  You can specify the same ORACLE_BASE and ORACLE_HOME. Just specify a different location for the data files.

Comment: To add to what @EdStevens said, you can (and should) use the same ASM storage that you would use for RAC. It will keep your storage management consistent and would allow you to convert the DB to RAC later if you so desired.